# How to properly escape [] characters in a Dockerfile CMD and ENTRYPOINT exec mode?

Tags: python, docker

I have a Dockerfile set up with a CMD statement similar to the folowing:

```
CMD python app.py \
    keyword1=value1 \
    keyword1.keyword1a=[/some/path/here/,/and/another/path/] \
    +keyword1.keyword1b=value3 \
    keyword2=[config.yaml] \
    keyword3=null
```

I would like to modify it into some combined ENTRYPOINT + CMD statements, so that the script arguments can be changed more easily. Like so:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
CMD ["keyword1=value1", \
    "keyword1.keyword1a=[/some/path/here/,/and/another/path/]", \
    "+keyword1.keyword1b=value3", \
    "keyword2=[config.yaml]", \
    "keyword3=null", \
]
```

However, this does not parse the command properly, showing me messages such as:

<s>/bin/sh: 1: [python,: not found</s>

```
app.py: error: argument --cfg/-c: invalid choice: '[     "keyword1=value1"     "keyword1.keyword1a=[/some/path/here/,/and/another/path/]"     "+keyword1.keyword1b=value3"     "keyword2=[config.yaml]"     "keyword3=null"]' (choose from 'job', 'hydra', 'all')
```

I get a different looking error if I try to put all arguments into ENTRYPOINT (or CMD) as exec form:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py", \
    "keyword1=value1", \
    "keyword1.keyword1a=[/some/path/here/,/and/another/path/]", \
    "+keyword1.keyword1b=value3", \
    "keyword2=[config.yaml]", \
    "keyword3=null", 
]
```

```
/bin/sh: 1: [python,: not found
```

I suspect the main problem is how the system considers the [] brackets: if I remove the lines containing those, the command seems to be parsed properly (but of course the python script does not do what I want it to).

Is there a good way to escape the problematic characters?

Comment: If you're seeing that message, the problem is specifically in the `ENTRYPOINT` line.  Is the rest of that line a valid JSON array, with ASCII "straight" double quotes around each word?  (It looks okay in the question, but if it doesn't parse correctly Docker will fall back to running it in shell mode, and that produces the `[python,` message.)

Comment: My apologies, that error message was actually from a slightly different case where I tried to put all arguments into the ENTRYPOINT line. Let me edit the question to put the correct error message in with the correct test case.

Comment: Actually, I think I found the problem... I had an extra comma at the end of my list for uniformity, but it looks like that was what was causing trouble. Thank you for the "valid JSON array" pointer!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem following David's comment: it looks like my trailing comma in the list was the culprit. This works:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
CMD ["keyword1=value1", \
    "keyword1.keyword1a=[/some/path/here/,/and/another/path/]", \
    "+keyword1.keyword1b=value3", \
    "keyword2=[config.yaml]", \
    "keyword3=null"]
```

It looks like the []s were not the problem.